# Error with Tweepy API

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm new to using Tweepy and I've just been trying to execute this line of code from a youtube tutorial but keep getting the error.  Anyone know what's going on?  Here's my code

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

res = api.search(q="IPython")
```

Errror:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py",
>   line 186, in execute
>       auth=auth, UnboundLocalError: local variable 'auth' referenced before assignment

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/christopherdimitrisastropranoto/Desktop/twitterAnalysis/Listener.py",
>   line 22, in 
>       trending = trial.trends_place(1)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py",
>   line 245, in _call
>       return method.execute()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py",
>   line 189, in execute
>       raise TweepError('Failed to send request: %s' % e) tweepy.error.TweepError: Failed to send request: local variable 'auth'
>   referenced before assignment

Comment: You posted your secret keys to the public.

Comment: Are those credentials the same that were used in the youtube tutorial, or did you replace those credentials with your own twitter credentials? I replaced those `key`/`secret`s/`token` with my credentials and I got back 15 results. Ensure you have registered a twitter API app and are indeed using your credentials registered to your app. Regardless of all that, as others mentioned be careful to *never* post private credentials to the public.

Comment: Yeah, I just looked at my sweary robot twitter client and it's exactly the same connection method:

Comment: https://github.com/keefbaker/SwearyRobot/blob/master/SwearyRobot.py it may just be your creds. (sorry how badly written this is, I wrote it in my early days and I'm trying to fix it up now)

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic setup structure you should have before you make any kind of API requests:

```
import tweepy

consumer_key = "X-U" #this you get when you make create an application on twitter as a dev
consumer_secret = "Z" #this you get when you make create an application on twitter as a dev

acess_token = "Y-V" #this you get when you make create an application on twitter as a dev
acess_token_secret = "P" #this you get when you make create an application on twitter as a dev


auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(acess_token, acess_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
```

Then you could try something like:

```
tweet = api.search(q="IPython")
```

And then if you want to print the text of the tweet:

```
t = tweet.text
print(t)
```